# How to program a discord.py bot to dm me when a command is used by another person?

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I want to create a command that people can use to send suggestions to me. They'd use the command "!suggest", followed by their input, and the bot privately dms that whole message to me. However I am struggling with making the bot dm me instead of the author of the command.

```
if message.content.startswith('!suggest'):
            await message.author.send(message.content)
```

The problem here lies with the `author` part in the code- instead of dming me every time, it will dm the person who typed the command, which is useless to me. How can I replace 'author' with my discord ID, to make it dm me and only me with the message? I've asked this before and all answers have not worked for me. These are the solution's I've gotten that did not work:

`message.author.dm_channel.send("message")`, but that is the same problem, it does not get rid of the author issue.

```
me = await client.get_user_info('MY_SNOWFLAKE_ID')
await client.send_message(me, "Hello!")
```

This code also did not work for me. The user that it is dming is the same each time, so I have no need to run the get_user_info in the first place. And whenever the second line runs, I get an error code because the MyClient cannot use the send_message attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is from the old discord version. It has been changed in the discord.py rewrite. I also recommend you to use [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html) instead of using `on_message` to read commands manually.
As for the dm, simply use

```
your_id = 123456789012345678
me = client.get_user(your_id)
await me.send("Hello")
```

Note that it requires members intents enabled. Use `await fetch_user(your_id)` if you don't have it enabled. Also, note that there might be also rate-limiting consequences if multiple users use commands simultaneously.

> **Docs:**

- [`get_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user)
- [`fetch_user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user)
- [`User.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.send)

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, message = None):
       if message == None:
           await ctx.send("Provide a suggestion")
       else:
          await ctx.{your_id}.send("message")
```

Please don't mind the indent

Answer (score 0):

You can dm a user by doing this:

```py
user = client.get_user(your_id_here)
await user.send('work!')
```

FAQ : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-dm

if you want the full code here it is:

```py
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, suggest_text):
       user_suggestor = ctx.author
       user = client.get_user(user_id) # replace the user_id to your user id
       if suggest_text == None:
           await ctx.send("Enter your suggestion! example : !suggest {your suggest here}")
       else:
           await user.send(f"{user_suggestor.name} sent an suggestion! \nSuggestion : {suggest_text}") # the \n thing is to space
```

thank me later :D

Comment: I still keep getting the error when I use ```user = client.get_user```, it keeps saying that it has no attribute of 'send'.